# If $f\in C^0(\overline{\Omega})$ is subharmonic and $-f$ is subharmonic, too, then $f\in C^2(\Omega)$ and $\Delta f=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain and $f\in C^0(\overline{\Omega})$ be *subharmonic*, i.e. for each closed ball $\overline{B}\subseteq\Omega$ it holds: $$u\in C^2(B)\text{ is harmonic in }B\text{ and }f\le u\text{ on }\partial B\;\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\;f\le u\text{ in }B\tag{1}$$ Now, suppose that $-f$ is subharmonic, too. How can we conclude that we must have $f\in C^2(\Omega)$ and $\Delta f=0$?

I think we need to do the following:

- Let $B\subset\subset\Omega$ be a ball and $u\in C^0(\overline{B})\cap C^2(B)$ harmonic with $$u\equiv f\;\;\;\text{on }\partial B\tag{2}$$
- Since the Dirichlet problem on the ball is uniquely solvable, $u$ is uniquely determined
- Since $f$ and $-f$ are subharmonic we've got $$f\le u\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;-f\le u\;\;\;\;\;\text{in B}$$ by $(1)$ and $(2)$. Thus, $$f\equiv u\;\;\;\text{in }B\tag{3}$$

$B$ was arbitrary. However, depending on $B$ we might get different $u$'s. How do we need to argue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real need to pass to the Dirichlet problem on balls contained in the domain. The point is that:

1. if $f$ is subharmonic on $\Omega$, then $-f$ is superharmonic on $\Omega$;
2. if $f$ is both subharmonic and superharmonic on $\Omega$ then $f$ is harmonic on $\Omega$;
3. if $f$ is harmonic (in the mean value sense) and continuous then $f \in C^2$, and hence $\Delta f = 0$ (in the classical sense).

Prove these three statements.

Comment: I know these statements and it's trivial to prove them. But I don't understand how they imply $\Delta f=0$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d That amounts to asking whether $f \in C^2$ if it is continuous and harmonic (in the mean value sense). There are various ways to prove that. One is by mollification, cf. http://www.math.harvard.edu/~canzani/math253/Lecture5.pdf

Comment: Maybe to your surprise, I know the third statement too. So, I think you want me to show, that $f$ satisfies the mean value property, right? From $(3)$ in my question, it's easy to see, that $f$ indeed satisfies this property - so we're done, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes. I'm sorry if I came across as condescending, by the way. I didn't intend to. My intent was only to convey that this problem is considerably easier than a lot of the other statements that you have already developed, provided you view it the right way. One catch is that the exact details here depend on how you initially define "subharmonic" and "superharmonic". I've usually seen these defined through the mean value inequalities, but when you define them through the existence of harmonic minorants/majorants, the problem is a little bit more complicated.